# Unescape some entities during xsl transformation

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, saxon, saxparser, xslt-3.0

We have done an xsl transformation to convert hexcode values into entities.
Now after transformation, there are some entites which are converting into their corresponding values like `&amp;` gets converted into '&', similar is the case for `&sect;`.
For keeping the entities unchanged, we have used the below xsl code:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='3.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' >
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" use-character-maps="mdash" />
<xsl:character-map name="mdash">
<xsl:output-character character="&#x2014;" string="&amp;mdash;"/>
<xsl:output-character character="&amp;" string="&amp;amp;" />
<xsl:output-character character="&quot;" string="&amp;quot;" />
<xsl:output-character character="&apos;" string="&amp;apos;" />
<xsl:output-character character="&sect;" string="&amp;sect;" />
</xsl:character-map>
<!--=================================================================-->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<!--=================================================================-->
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now transformation happens fine for most of the entities, but for &sect, the below error is displayed:-

```
SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The entity "sect" was referenced, but not declared.
```

Is there a way to unescape this entity sect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a numeric character reference e.g. `&#167;`:

```
<xsl:output-character character="&#167;" string="&amp;sect;" />
```

Comment: Alternatively, include a DOCTYPE in the stylesheet that declares the entities you want to reference.